# Search table and combine rows with identical A and B columns and add their value in C column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to search the entire table (1200+ rows) and combine rows where A AND B columns are identical, and add their C column values.

If column A and column B are identical to any other rows, then those rows are to combined and their values in column C are to be added.

```
apple  orange 2

apple  banana 1

apple  orange 5
```

would result in:

```
apple   orange 7

apple   banana 1
```

How do I do this in Excel?
Pivot table is not an option.

Comment: Are you familiar with VBA macros in Excel, or only excel functions?

Comment: Beginner only. Mostly excel functions.

Answer (score 0):

@wwl  I have modified this existing answer to hopefully offer you a closer match to what you're after -

Your data result lends itself to the Data -> SubTotal routine.
With some slight adjustments you can get a Total figure (Sum) of each identical match.

Create a temporary joining column to merge the Column A & B together for easier manipulation. To save additional presentation editing later in this solution, use a joining formula which includes a space.

```
C2=A2&" "&B2       (Don't include the "C2" in the actual cell!)
```

You copy this formula down the list to the bottom.
Then you should sort your list as A->Z, based on the new column formula results, to allow all identical matches to group together.

[image]

You then highlight your data table, and select the "Data -> SubTotal" menu function. This will pop up a window to make particular choices, as the function goes through your list and tries to create a "SubTotal" of each grouped match.

[image]

Read through the function options carefully (and literally, as the window walks you through what is to happen), and it should make sense to your particular columns and headings. (ie. follow your sheet specifically if different to this example).

So, this time around I am using the SubTotal function results more efficiently, by simply collapsing the generated groupings.

[image]

Select the (2) second level box on the left side of cells and this will collapse the groups to just the sub-total headings. Then to tidy up the display you can hide columns A & B.

No conditional formatting was added to this simpler version of the solution.

[image]

Comment: Kram, many thanks! Although this only gets me half way. My goal is to en up with only one row of each fruit combination and only the total number of fruit in colC, not the "raw data". is that possible to include in the solution you have done above?

Comment: Yes, I have slightly adjusted the above answer (on my Excel) to show a "number" then the "fruit". It uses the same technique, but changes "sub-total from bottom to top of each sub-group. The formula on the right of list to copy down is adjusted as well, to account for simpler display (not showing "Total").  I'll make some examples and post soon.

Comment: @wwl  Check out the updated solution, and hopefully there's a tick and vote in there somewhere!  ;-)

Comment: @wwl How did that solution go? Did it help?